# get the maximum value in scala map along with the key

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Can anybody help how to get the the maximum value in a map along with its key.
For example map below:

```
Map(s -> 3, h -> 2, M -> 1, q-> 4)
```

I should get the key value (q -> 4) as the 4 is the highest.

I tried the max method,keys and values iterator. But none of the return both key and value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does this look like for you?

```
map.maxBy { case (key, value) => value }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `maxBy` as

```
val map_values = Map("s" -> 3, "h" -> 2, "M" -> 1, "q"-> 4)
println(map_values.maxBy(_._2))
//(q,4)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get what you want as follows:

```
 map.filter{case (k,v) => v == map.values.max}
```

With `map.values.max` you get the max value, and inserting it into the `filter` statement you obtain the whole key-value pair

Comment: This answer is more complete, because unlike the other answers, this yields all keys that have the max value, not just a single one of them, when multiple keys have the same max value. Of course, for a very large map or critical code sections, you might want something finer for performance sake.